# Debug mode without debug build DLLs

Tags: qt

I am looking for a way to compile and debug my Qt application linked with release builds of Qt DLLs. More specifically, I want to do a "debug build" but link against "release builds" of Qt DLLs. There is a standard way to do that? Or the only alternative is to do a "release build" with debugging information added?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows, you can do this

```
#if defined(_DEBUG) && defined(USE_DEBUG_QT)
#pragma comment(lib, "QtCored4.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "QtGuid4.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "QtOpenGLd4.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "QtCore4.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "QtGui4.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "QtOpenGL4.lib")
#endif
```